# Visual Studio 2019 SSIS dtexec config file Azure Blob Key

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019, configuration-files, ssis-2019

**My question is around : *storing Azure blob key in config file*.**

Below is the picture of my package overview. I'm trying to pull data from Oracle source and put a flat file on Azure blob storage (in csv format). That is the scope of this SSIS package.
Right side of picture shares that I can execute the package via commandline if `**Protection level =' EncryptSensistiveWithUserKey' **`

But NOW packages need to be run via a service account and not developer, architects accounts.
Looping back into my question: HOW do I store blob key in config file by setting the `**Protection level = 'DONOTSAVESENSITIVE'**` . Config file code after the package overview.
[image: VS2019 SSIS Package overview]

Config File currently being used

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><DTSConfiguration><DTSConfigurationHeading><DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="BI\MonkeyMan" GeneratedFromPackageName="Package" GeneratedFromPackageID="{9BDF0000-CAC9-4823-A6D8-EE59C3BB31A0}" GeneratedDate="4/6/2020 6:48:57 PM"/></DTSConfigurationHeading><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[Prod v18].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
<ConfiguredValue>SERVER=1.1.1.01:1521/DB;USERNAME=MonkeyMan;WINAUTH=0;data source=1.1.1.01:1521/DB;user id=MonkeyMan;password=isharemypasswords;
</ConfiguredValue></Configuration></DTSConfiguration>
```

Finally picture of when I try to run the package via dtexec with protection level set to DO NOT SAVE SENSITIVE.
[image: ERROR VIA DTEXEC]
Thanks for all your help around this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to use the builtin config-editor and select the properties you want to save to the config file.

Here's one tutorial to set it up: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-package-configuration-using-xml-configuration-file/

Comment: Hi @Gigga thanks for letting me know. Have tried this and at times password for source(s) is not saved correctly. BUT I will re-do this step all over again.